# word usage: "furtivamente" and "a escondidas"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

Do "furtivamente" and "a escondidas" both mean "secretly"?
They are interchangeable?

> For example:
>   1. entró furtivamente en la habitación.
>   2. entro a escondidas en la habitación.

The meanings are the same?

Comment: By the way, I think you understand Spanish quite well. I encourage you to make your questions in Spanish. Don't worry if you make mistakes, we'll help you. Spanish is preferred in this site: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq#should-i-post-in-spanish-or-english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both have the same meaning and they are interchangeable: hidden, without being seen, secretly.

You can see their definitions, both are synonyms.

[a escondidas](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=a%20escondidas&val_aux=&origen=REDRAE):

> 1. loc. adv. Sin ser visto.

[Furtivamente](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=furtivamente&val_aux=&origen=REDRAE) is a synonym for [ocultamente](http://rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=furtivamente&val_aux=&origen=REDRAE):

> 1. adv. m. Con secreto, y sin que se entienda ni perciba.
> 2. adv. m. Escondidamente, sin ser visto ni oído.